# Google Earth Engine: Button to Refresh App

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google

I would like to have a refresh button on a GEE app that reruns my whole script. I want the user to be able to set a rectangle on the map that holds all of the analysis (the app is basically a classifier that's bound to the rectangle), refresh the script to run it, then be able to move the rectangle to another spot and refresh the script again. So far this is what I have, and the map does refresh but the analysis within the rectangle does not move from its initial state.

```
var newMap = ui.root.widgets().get(0)


var refresh = ui.Button({
  label: 'Run', 
  onClick: function () {
  ui.root.clear()
  ui.root.add(newMap)
  }
});

Map.add(refresh);
```

Comment: You may want to try Map.clear()

Answer (score 0):

Users can't cause the script to be re-run.
Instead, use the Drawing tools widget.  There's a full example script in the community tutorials:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/drawing-tools#example_classification_with_user-drawn_geometries